# IntelliJ IDEA Test Coverage window doesn't show

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm using Spring Boot project with the last version of IntelliJ IDEA (2018.2.1 Ultimate Edition).

When I run all my test with coverage the Coverage window doesn't show, and there's no percentage beside my main classes.

I've tried enabling the coverage window by going to `View -> Tool Windows -> Coverage`, but the coverage tab is disabled (not clickable).

[image]

If I remember correctly the coverage was working fine before I update IntelliJ. Is that a bug with the last version ?

**Edit**
the coverage plugin is already installed
[image]

Comment: Try to reinstall Intellij IDEA. When installing, he asks about install the "Coverage" plugin.

Comment: If it's a matter of the plugin not being installed, you don't have to reinstall the IDE to solve it...just install the plugin.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Guys the coverage plugin is already installed, see my edit !

Comment: @K.Ayoub please share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I ran tests with coverage of the SpringBoot app with IntelliJ IDEA **2018.2** (Build #IU-182.3684.101, built on July 24, 2018) and then with IntelliJ IDEA **2018.2.1** (Build #IU-182.3911.36, built on August 6, 2018) Coverage window showed in both cases. So it doesn't look like an update issue.

Comment: Have you tried the `Analyze | Show Coverage Data...` menu item?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers yes it gives me "No coverage suites configured"

Comment: In case anyone else ran into this: In my case, that plugin had become disabled after my JetBrains subscription temporarily expired. I had to re-enable it and then re-activate it.

Answer (score 9):

For me, I verified all the settings in Intellij and all were correct. My test class was in the wrong package due to which Intellij was not showing the coverage.

If the code is in the package: *com.company.domain.module*
test class should also be in *com.company.domain.module*

Once I corrected the package, the coverage started appearing.

Comment: This did work. But what if I want my test package name to be different?

Answer (score 7):

Potentially the Coverage plugin is installed but disabled on your machine e.g. IntelliJ wasn't restarted after plugin was enabled. Try restarting after double checking that Coverage plugin is enabled. As per [IntelliJ Code Coverage docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-coverage.html):

> ### Prerequisite
>
> Make sure the Code Coverage plugin is enabled. The plugin is activated by default. If the plugin is disabled, enable it on the Plugins settings page as described in Managing Plugins. If the plugin is disabled, the code coverage tabs will not be visible in the run/debug configuration dialogs.

Try opening Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Coverage and check the "Activate Coverage View" checkbox. After that run another test with Coverage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i checked all what's you say but nothing works.

Comment: @K.Ayoub are you running IntelliJ on some kind of ancient JDK 6 or beading edge JDK 10/11?

Comment: I'm running Intellij on JDK 10

Comment: @K.Ayoub coverage is based on bytecode instrumentation or other low level JDK features. Try downgrading to 8 or 9 and see if it helps with this particular plugin.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with JDK or latest version of IntelliJ.

Here is the step you follow and see the coverage window. Run project with coverage, sometimes coverage window not shown if you are unable to see coverage window then

- press **shift+f9**
- then press on **stop and rerun**

After this, your coverage window is shown.

Still, if you are unable to see coverage window then please double check is coverage view enable or not follow these steps:

- press **ctrl+alt+s**
- extend **build, execution and deployment**
- press **coverage**
- select first radio box and activate coverage view
- press apply and then ok

Again follow the above step run with coverage, press shift+f9 etc.

Hope this help.

Comment: The first radio box already selected, the shift+f9 didn't help.

Comment: After running with coverage, press on debugging then it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

Try and go to

```
Run-->edit configurations-->select code coverage ( then you can select IDEA/EMMA/...)
```

Comment: Intellij Idea is selected by default.

Answer (score 2):

The package of the classes was the issue for me.
The test class and the source class should have same package path

For example-

If the code is in the package: *src.main.***com.company.domain.module**
test class should also be in *src.test.***com.company.domain.module**

You can either rename your packages

OR

If you don't want to rename your packages, then try this

**Modify run configurations -> Code Coverage -> You will see the path of test class there. Add your source classes path also.**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you have figured the solution till date but I ran with the same issue and got solved.

In my case, the issue was with coverage jars were not able to pick up due to spaces on the directory name.

Please follow below thread and let me know if it helps.

[Intellij Coverage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742666/test-coverage-not-working-in-intellij-idea)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is looking for the same issue, I found the option in More Run/Debug section.

Comment: "Collect coverage in test folders".  It's a same this needs to be remembered to be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, all the settings in IntelliJ were correct. My test class was in the wrong package due to which IntelliJ was not showing the coverage.

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72973840/7099872, if the code is in the package `com.company.domain.module` test class should also be in `com.company.domain.module`.

However, instead of changing packages names, you can add coverage using below steps if you really need to use a different package naming.

Go to Modify run configurations.

[image: menu]

Then add the actual (production code) package.

[image: code coverage package]

After running with coverage, now the production class is covered. When you open the production class, its lines would be highlighted using red/green lines.

[image: coverage report]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by selecting the root of my project as source folder.
Do:
"project view" -> Right click root folder -> "mark directory as" -> "Source root"